# Groovy performance on Linux machine

Tags: performance, redhat-enterprise-linux, groovy

I have a problem when I start Groovy on one of my Linux machines - it takes about 30 seconds to execute very simple command:

```
groovy -e ""
```

if I run `strace` on it, here is what I see where it stops and waits:

```
mprotect(0x7fae284e0000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fae285dfff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fae285e09d0, tls=0x7fae285e0700, child_tidptr=0x7fae285e09d0) = 62660
futex(0x7fae285e09d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 62660, NULL <unfinished ...>
```

Is there a way to figure out what it's waiting for and why and how to fix it?

I am running Red Hat 6.3, Groovy Version: 2.2.1 JVM: 1.7.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

And here is time command:

bin$ time groovy -e ""

real    0m22.255s
user    0m26.875s
sys     0m2.064s

Comment: The latest version of Groovy being?  It helps to have specific version numbers.  Are you running the latest package for your distro, the latest stable release, the latest beta, the latest nightly?

Comment: Groovy Version: 2.2.1 JVM: 1.7.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

Answer (score 0):

Reason of groovy's very long startup time (compared to other interpreted languages) is that is has to fire up a JVM for every `groovy`-command.

You might want to look into [GroovyServ](https://kobo.github.io/groovyserv/). What this does is running a daemon with a JVM in the background the first time you start it. Subsequent calls of `groovyclient` then use this JVM instead. It promises to be "10 to 20 times faster than regular Groovy".

Comment: I don't think it was the case since the same call works much faster on another server with similar hardware. And java runs faster as well, nowhere near 30 second delays.